# networking in android

Tags: android, networking

i had to develop a app in android for mobile blogging (to update a site by this app).
How can i develop this app..pls any one give a overview..

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/index.html

Install the SDK, read the tutorials, get started. Then come back with specific questions once they pop up.

Comment: ya am having. i have designed user interface in mobile side...i want details how to communicate with website and how send a meg to website?

Comment: Show what you've done so far. Post some code you need help with. Explain what exactly you mean with "communicate with website". I guess you won't get better answers if you leave people guessing and/or expect them to post a whole solution for you out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

If your website supports XML-RPC (like Wordpress) you can build your own too (or use an existing one)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Weblog_Client