# Is there any open source game networking engine for android?

Tags: android, game-engine, android-networking

I am developing a multiplayer game for Android. There are plenty of game engines for android out there but having separate physics and networking engine would be great to reduce size and to brought two best engines in one single app. I looked at [RakNet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/) but Its not open source as well as not free.

I looked at some threads here as well [networking in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883740/networking-in-android) and [Android networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110629/android-networking) , but there answer suggest low level interface rather than out-of-the-box networking library needed for games (handling lags, packet loss, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Hope these links are useful:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-networking/

http://www.exitgames.com/Photon/Mobile_Core

http://code.google.com/p/android-juice/

http://code.google.com/p/mages/

http://www.androidtechblog.info/multiplayer-social-gaming-platform-for-iphone-and-android-phones/

http://androiddoesitbetter.com/android-phones/multiplayer-social-gaming-platform-for-iphone-and-android-phones/

Comment: all you pointed out are game engines not specialized networking engine.

Comment: @Gagandeep Singh Please see the updated links, found some more & interesting.